# POST file upload works with curl but not with Qt (seafile web api)

Tags: c++, qt, http, curl, network-programming

I'm trying to upload a file from c++ Qt5 code using the seafile web api (https://github.com/haiwen/seafile/wiki/Seafile-web-API#upload-file).

The API works well with curl, but with Qt I got a "400 Bad Request" from apache.

I used wireshark to see the differences in the requests. With curl :

```
curl -k -F "file=@/tmp/test_up.txt; filename=qt.txt" -F parent_dir=/ myserver.com/seafhttp/upload-api/f8e70ecc
```

gives me

```
POST /seafhttp/upload-api/f8e70ecc HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.37.0
Host: myserver.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 292
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------9a2b257b2a34c31f

--------------------------9a2b257b2a34c31f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="qt.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test up

--------------------------9a2b257b2a34c31f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parent_dir"

/
--------------------------9a2b257b2a34c31f--
```

Now the Qt source:

```
QHttpMultiPart *multipart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart file_part;
file_part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"qt.txt\"")); //
file_part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("text/plain"));
QFile *file = new QFile{"/tmp/test_up.txt"};
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
file_part.setBodyDevice(file);
file->setParent(multipart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multipart

QHttpPart parent_dir_part;
parent_dir_part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"parent_dir\""));
parent_dir_part.setBody("/");

multipart->append(file_part);
multipart->append(parent_dir_part);

QNetworkRequest request{server + upload_url};
_reply = _manager.post(request, multipart);
multipart->setParent(_reply); // delete the multipart with the reply
```

gives me

```
POST /seafhttp/upload-api/f8e70ecc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary_.oOo._MTgzMTcwMjYyNg==MTc3NDExNzExNg==NTI2MDQyOTI1"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 349
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,en,*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: myserver.com

--boundary_.oOo._MTgzMTcwMjYyNg==MTc3NDExNzExNg==NTI2MDQyOTI1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="qt.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

test up

--boundary_.oOo._MTgzMTcwMjYyNg==MTc3NDExNzExNg==NTI2MDQyOTI1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parent_dir"

/
--boundary_.oOo._MTgzMTcwMjYyNg==MTc3NDExNzExNg==NTI2MDQyOTI1--
```

Server-side I have these logs for the two requests:

```
myserver.com - - [02/Jun/2014:15:20:18 +0200] "POST /seafhttp/upload-api/f8e70ecc HTTP/1.1" 200 166 "-" "curl/7.37.0"
myserver.com - - [02/Jun/2014:15:21:28 +0200] "POST /seafhttp/upload-api/f8e70ecc HTTP/1.1" 400 103 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Now the two requests seem very close and I use nothing fancy in the Qt code, following the QHttpMultiPart documentation example.
I tried changing the UserAgent or the boundary to get even closer to curl, without success.

One difference I remarked in the traffic though, is that when I use curl it waits for a "Continue" before sending the rest of the data :

```
[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
[ACK]
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
[ACK]
[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
[ACK]
POST /seafhttp/upload-api/f8e70ecc HTTP/1.1  (text/plain)
[ACK]
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Whereas with Qt it goes like this :

```
[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
[ACK]
POST /seafhttp/upload-api/f8e70ecc HTTP/1.1  (text/plain)
[ACK]
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

This is not really my main domain, so I'm not sure **what can I do to debug further** ?

Any hint appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after rewriting manually the requests until it work I found the solution. This seems to be a bug **server-side**.

Qt add double quotes around the boundary declaration in the header which appears to respect the rfc (see a closed bug here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29744).

Anyway the workaround is straightforward, I just rewrote the header without the quotes:

```
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + multipart->boundary());
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if it is satisfactory.

Comment: @FinalContest Yes this is the actual solution, but I must wait to accept